# htaccess rewrite ?p= (I don't understand the code)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I think I have read everything I can about htaccess rewrites and I still can't make heads or tails of whats going on. I re made a website for work and all is well except the last designer did some crazy php stuff and all the urls he used have ?=p(pagename) I want to rewite those to (pagename).php then redirect them to with a 301 I am able to get the 301 redirects works just can't figure out how to rewrite the ?p=(pagename) to (pagename).php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be matching against the actual requests, then internally rewrite it back to the query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

# 301 redirect to php file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /\?p=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php?%2 [L,R=301]

# internally rewrite to the query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much I have been trying to do that for weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the QUERY_STRING and then apply the rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/%1.php [R=301,L]
```

the `^p=(.*)$` checks for a query string that only has the one variable `p=pagename`, you will have to modify it if there will be any other variables in the query string it like `p=pagename&id=15` etc